# Does anyone know the formula used by SO to calculate the <priority> in the sitemap?

Tags: discussion, seo, sitemap

https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml (you need to impersonate google to see it)

I think the `<priority>` field is handled really well. Questions with many answers and/or upvotes have higher priority..

I wonder if anyone knows the exact formula they're using to calculate it. Thanks!

Comment: "you need to impersonate google to see it" Why would this be? Don't they want to show up on other search engines? Are they trying to increase the barrier to entry for new search engines into the market? This seems about as short-sighted as any other sort of user-agent detection, and a good way to reduce the openness of the web.

Comment: @Brian: I don't know, but lets go around it!

Comment: What's formula do you using? can you post an answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918106/algorithm-for-calculate-siteamps-priority-value-based-on-views-comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early days they discussed the ranking algorithm for the front page quite a bit, but they never released what they ultimately settled on.

My expectation is that they are likely using the same algorithm.

As for what it is, they've only hinted at the path they took to develop it.  You might try searching the stackoverflow blog for entries mentioning "ranking."  This link might do the job:

http://www.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-6254779591266030%3Awa6mxc6y8y6&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=ranking&sa=Search

Comment: I checked out (okay, quickly) all the results, but none seem related to the sitemap. :( Anyways, +1 for trying, thanks

Comment: No, as I said they haven't discussed the sitemap.  I'm theorizing that the algorithm is likely to be very similar, if not the same as the algorithm used to determine what questions are 'hot' on the front page.

Comment: can you try search again?